# Varnish - PURGE request does not purge hash_data() URL

Tags: varnish, vcl, varnish-vcl

In vcl_hash, I have

```
backend default {
        .host = "127.0.0.1";
        .port = "8080";
}
acl purge {
        "localhost";
}
sub vcl_hash {
        if(req.http.Cookie ~ "isLogin") {
                hash_data("1");
        }
}
sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                        error 405 "Not allowed.";
                }
                return (lookup);
        }
        return(lookup);
}
sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}
sub vcl_miss {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                purge;
                error 404 "Not in Cache.";
        }
}
```

I am using below command to purge urls.
curl -X PURGE http://release.com/user/details

If url is cached for logged-out users, I get below output

```
curl -X PURGE http://release.com/user/details
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>200 Purged.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error 200 Purged.</h1>
    <p>Purged.</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: 1071483546</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If it is cached only for logged-in users, I keep getting below output. (Even though url is making "Hits")

```
curl -X PURGE http://release.com/user/details
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>404 Not in Cache.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error 404 Not in Cache.</h1>
    <p>Not in Cache.</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: 998719206</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://release.com/user/details looks different on the basis if user is logged in or not. (ie it has isLogin cookie or not). PURGE is not working for urls that were hashed in vcl_hash. 
Seems to be an error or feature of Varnish. Please suggest, what can be done.

Comment: Have you confirmed that logged in users even get cached pages at all? Generally responses coming back with Set-Cookie aren't going to be cached (unless you are overriding that)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I having the same problem using varnish 4.1

Comment: @DavidStone perhaps my answer can help you

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem in my case probably it's the same for you and anyone using vcl_hash with purge. The hash is used for the purge so all the request information used for the has hash to be present for doing the purge. In your case you checking the cookie `if(req.http.Cookie ~ "isLogin")` so you must send this cookie with the purge request like:

```
curl -X PURGE --cookie "isLogin=1" http://release.com/user/details
```

If you want to purge all variants of the hash you'll need to call it twice, once with the cookie and once without.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar scenario. We want to serve different content to mobile & desktop users (depending on the User-Agent).

We are doing it without changing the object hash. We are using different variants (Vary) of the same object. Read the [cache invalidation documentation](http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/Cache_Invalidation.html).

We are using a custom header that is added in the `beresp.http.Vary` (we also use this custom header in our backend).

In our scenario, it is mandatory to set the Vary header that is sent back to the users (including Google) so they know that the response depends on the User-Agent. We do it in `vcl_deliver`.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  ...

  if (req.restarts == 0) {
    # Change this code, we are using a CloudFront header
    if (req.http.CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer == "true") {
      set req.http.X-Device-Type = "mobile";
    } else {
      set req.http.X-Device-Type = "desktop";
    }
  }

  ...

  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ acl_purge) {
      return(synth(400, "Bad request."));
    }
    return(purge);
  }

  ...
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    ...

    if (beresp.http.Vary) {
      set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", " + "X-Device-Type";
    } else {
      set beresp.http.Vary = "X-Device-Type";
    }

    ...
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  ...

  set resp.http.Vary = "Accept-Encoding, User-Agent";

  ...
}
```

Comment: The code of this answer was written by [JacoboMarquis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9625729/jacobo-marquis)